# Link sentence with "By doing"

Tags: grammar

I am trying to find a way to link two sentences and was confused if I can use "by" here? 
"One way to solve this problem is to give equal job opportunities for everyone. By doing this, it will help .."

Usually, I would use a subject indicating the action in the first phrase, like: by doing this, we can... with doing is to refer to "we". 
Sorry if I make any grammar mistake, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Your grammar was all fine until "Sorry if I make any grammar _mistakes_ ..." ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly acceptable, since "doing this" is a dependent clause requiring a conjunction (since it is at the beginning of the sentence) and the "this" is referring to the previous sentence.

If any of that is unclear, ask away and I shall elaborate.